# Strip multiple tags with strip_tags()

Tags: php

I am trying to strip html tags from my msg string.

I have the following string that contains user input :

```
$msg="<a href="#">Hello world</a> ! <b>Welcome to venga club</b> .<br><li>We are here to entertain you....</li>";
```

I know it's simple to strip those tags with regex and preg_replace, but I want to do this using strip_tags() if possible.

I tried the following code

```
 echo strip_tags("<a><b><li><br>",$msg);
```

but the result i get is black, is there something wrong with the function?
Any help is much appriciated.

Thanks

Comment: For gods sake read a manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

like **@u_mulder** has advised - sometimes it is indeed worth to spare some additional time on reading the manual (evening reading etc.) :)

`function strip_tags ($str, $allowable_tags = null)`

accepts first argument as the input string and second argument as allowable tags. **Opposite** of how it is written in your case.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

so you should put it for example like this:

```
$msg='<a href="#">Hello world</a> ! <b>Welcome to venga club</b> .<br><li>We are here to entertain you....</li>';

echo strip_tags($msg, '<a>');
```